# What does 'across the level' mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'across the level' mean here, and 'striking off across' mean

> With a short laugh he threw it down on the bed, and pulling on his old
>   black hat, he went out, striking off **across the level**.

On the Divide
by Willa Cather

Answer (score 2):

The word "level" appears four times in that story. The first appearance is at the beginning, where it appears in the first sentence "... the level Nebraska plain...".
In the sentence you quote, it means that he walked across the land, which is very flat.

Comment: is it always the case, I mean is "level" synonymous with "plain" ? or is a case of a writer trying to be creative with the language?

Comment: @Fermichem https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/level#Noun 9. (*Britain*) An area of almost perfectly flat land.

Comment: What does 'striking off across' the level mean? Does it mean just - he went outside?

Comment: It means he left. "strike" can mean "(intransitive) To set off on a walk or trip." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strike#Verb

Comment: @boris thanks alot